# NHibernate dictionary mapping without primary key

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, nhibernate

**Question**
How to map dictionary collection cross database with the same .hbm configuration ?

**Scenario**
I am trying to map a dictionary property:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Phrases { set; get; }
```

with the following .hbm configuration:

```
<map
    name="Phrases"
    cascade="save-update"
    table="ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE"
    lazy="true">
        <key column="RESOURCE_ID" /> <!-- foreign key -->
        <index column="LOCALE_NAME" type="string" />
        <element column="PHRASE" type="string" />
</map>
```

and the following is the table create SQL of [ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE] for MS SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE ( 
    CUID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    RESOURCE_ID int NOT NULL,
    FIELD_NAME nvarchar(255) DEFAULT 'VALUE' NOT NULL,
    LOCALE_NAME nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PHRASE ntext NULL
);
```

but if I change my database from MS SQL Server to Oracle and Oracle database cannot use **IDENTITY(1, 1)** to generate the primary key automatically. In Oracle, I will have some trouble due to insert table with NULL Primary Key.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague recommend me to adjust the table schema.

1. Remove column `CUID` and `FIELD_NAME`
2. Let `RESOURCE_ID` and `LOCALE_NAME` be the **composite key**.
3. Let `RESOURCE_ID` be composite key and **foreign key** at the same time.

Indeed, above approach can solve my problem, but I don't this data schema design is good or not.

I would appreciate it if somebody have any advice for me about this data schema design.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the `ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE` table with a `native` generator rather than `identity`:

> For cross-platform development, the native strategy will choose from the identity, sequence and hilo strategies, dependent upon the capabilities of the underlying database ([ref](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-sequences)).

Oracle doesn't support the notion of an identity column. If you're using SQL Server 2012+, you can use sequences rather than identities. This would be more consistent with Oracle and is, arguably, a better key generation strategy ORM-wise.

Comment: In my requirement, ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE have to map a Dictionary property. I can't add .hbm and domain for ATTRIBUTE_LOCALE. Additionally,the .hbm configuration contain this <map> has used native generator to handle oracle's primary key.